# How to spyon/stub an http request in a flutter widget test

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I'm trying to give a value to `JsonPlaceholderService().getPlaceholder()` when it's called on button click in the widget test but it fails with

```
StateError (Bad state: No method stub was called from within `when()`. 
Was a real method called, or perhaps an extension method?)
```

home.dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertest/json_placeholder_service.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String text = '';

  Future<void> _onPressed() async {
    final response = await JsonPlaceholderService().getPlaceholder();
    setState(() {
      text = response.title;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text('Get text'),
              onPressed: () => _onPressed(),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 40),
            Text(text),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

json_placeholder_model.dart

```dart
class JsonPlaceholderModel {
  int id;
  int userId;
  String title;
  bool completed;

  JsonPlaceholderModel({
    required this.id,
    required this.userId,
    required this.title,
    required this.completed,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'id': id,
        'userId': userId,
        'title': title,
        'completed': completed,
      };

  JsonPlaceholderModel.fromJson(dynamic json)
      : id = json['id'],
        userId = json['userId'],
        title = json['title'],
        completed = json['completed'];
}
```

json_placeholder_service.dart

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:fluttertest/json_placeholder_model.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class JsonPlaceholderService {
  Future<JsonPlaceholderModel> getPlaceholder() async {
    const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    final data = jsonDecode(const Utf8Decoder().convert(response.bodyBytes));
    final JsonPlaceholderModel json = JsonPlaceholderModel.fromJson(data);
    return json;
  }
}
```

widget_test.dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:fluttertest/json_placeholder_model.dart';
import 'package:fluttertest/json_placeholder_service.dart';
import 'package:fluttertest/main.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';

void main() {
  testWidgets('Should display api text on button click',
      (WidgetTester tester) async {
    // Build our app and trigger a frame.
    await tester.pumpWidget(const MyApp());

    // Stub http request
    final json = {
      "userId": 1,
      "id": 1,
      "title": "delectus aut autem",
      "completed": false
    };
    final response = JsonPlaceholderModel.fromJson(json);
    // Methode 1 -> says to use methode 2
    when(JsonPlaceholderService().getPlaceholder())
        .thenReturn(Future.value(response));
    // Methode 2
    when(JsonPlaceholderService().getPlaceholder())
        .thenAnswer((_) async => response);

    // Click the button
    final button = find.byType(ElevatedButton);
    expect(button, findsOneWidget);
    await tester.tap(button);
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    await tester.pump(const Duration(seconds: 2));

    // The text is displayed
    expect(find.text('delectus aut autem'), findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```

All this code is available in this repo : https://github.com/TheSmartMonkey/flutter-http-widget-test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First  init your service in your widget constructor then it could be mocked

Second mock your service

main.dart

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp(client: JsonPlaceholderService()));
}
```

home.dart

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final JsonPlaceholderService client;

  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
    required this.client,
  }) : super(key: key);import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertest/json_placeholder_service.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final JsonPlaceholderService client;

  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
    required this.client,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String text = '';

  Future<void> _onPressed() async {
    final response = await widget.client.getPlaceholder();
    setState(() {
      text = response.title;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text('Get text'),
              onPressed: () => _onPressed(),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 40),
            Text(text),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

widget_test.dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:fluttertest/json_placeholder_model.dart';
import 'package:fluttertest/json_placeholder_service.dart';
import 'package:fluttertest/main.dart';
import 'package:mocktail/mocktail.dart';

class MockJsonPlaceholderService extends Mock
    implements JsonPlaceholderService {}

void main() {
  final mockJsonPlaceholderService = MockJsonPlaceholderService();

  testWidgets('Should display api text on button click',
      (WidgetTester tester) async {
    // Given
    // Build our app and trigger a frame.
    await tester.pumpWidget(
      MyApp(client: mockJsonPlaceholderService),
    );

    // When
    // Stub http request
    final json = {
      "userId": 1,
      "id": 1,
      "title": "delectus aut autem",
      "completed": false
    };
    final response = JsonPlaceholderModel.fromJson(json);
    when(() => mockJsonPlaceholderService.getPlaceholder())
        .thenAnswer((_) async => response);

    // Click the button
    final button = find.byType(ElevatedButton);
    expect(button, findsOneWidget);
    await tester.tap(button);
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    await tester.pump(const Duration(seconds: 2));

    // Then
    verify(() => mockJsonPlaceholderService.getPlaceholder()).called(1);
    expect(find.text('delectus aut autem'), findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```

article : https://gist.github.com/brianegan/414f6b369c534a0e5f20bff377823414

All this code is available in this repo : https://github.com/TheSmartMonkey/flutter-http-widget-test

Answer (score 1):

This is because you called a real method instead of calling a stub.
To mock a stub, you can use the [Mocktail](https://pub.dev/packages/mocktail) package (I prefer this over `mockito` because it is easier to use with null safety) and create a class `MockJsonPlaceholderService` that extends `Mock` from the `mocktail` package.

Then make the `JsonPlaceholderService` as a constructor argument of `MyApp` (this is known as dependency injection, you may refer to [this section of the article](https://codewithandrea.com/articles/flutter-singletons/#dependency-injection) for more details).

So that in your test, after you have created an instance of `MockJsonPlaceholderService`, you may define a stub method with:

```
when(() => mockJsonPlaceholderService.getPlaceholder()).thenReturn(yourMockResponse);
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I tryed mocktail but now I have a `FormatException (FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 1)` on the getPlaceholder() jsonDecode. response is empty for some reason then response.bodyBytes is empty that triggers this error

Comment: If you want to do some tests : https://github.com/TheSmartMonkey/flutter-http-widget-test

Comment: I saw from your repo that you didn't put the mock service instance into your widget `MyApp`. You need to inject that instance into your pumped widget in order to use the mock.